# xpath does not work with this site, pls verify

Tags: python, parsing, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I using Python with selenium (PhantomJS webdriver) to parse websites and i have problem with it.

I want to get current song from this radio site: http://www.eskago.pl/radio/eska-warszawa.

xpath:

```
/html/body/div[3]/div[1]/section[2]/div/div/div[2]/ul/li[2]/a[2]
```

that xpath does not work with python selenium

error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "parser4.py", line 41, in
>   
>       p.loop()   File "parser4.py", line 37, in loop
>       self.eska(self.url_eskawarszawa)   File "parser4.py", line 27, in eska
>       driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[3]/div[1]/section[2]/div/div/div[2]/ul/li[2]/a[2]')
>   File
>   "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py",
>   line 230, in find_element_by_xpath
>       return self.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value=xpath)   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py",
>   line 662, in find_element
>       {'using': by, 'value': value})['value']   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py",
>   line 173, in execute
>       self.error_handler.check_response(response)   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py",
>   line 164, in check_response
>       raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace) selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message:
>   u'{"errorMessage":"Unable to find element with xpath
>   \'/html/body/div[3]/div[1]/section[2]/div/div/div[2]/ul/li[2]/a[2]\'","request":{"headers":{"Accept":"application/json","Accept-Encoding":"identity","Connection":"close","Content-Length":"148","Content-Type":"application/json;charset=UTF-8","Host":"127.0.0.1:55583","User-Agent":"Python-urllib/2.7"},"httpVersion":"1.1","method":"POST","post":"{\"using\":
>   \"xpath\", \"sessionId\":
>   \"e2fa7700-1bea-11e4-bd11-83e129ae286e\", \"value\":
>   \"/html/body/div[3]/div[1]/section[2]/div/div/div[2]/ul/li[2]/a[2]\"}","url":"/element","urlParsed":{"anchor":"","query":"","file":"element","directory":"/","path":"/element","relative":"/element","port":"","host":"","password":"","user":"","userInfo":"","authority":"","protocol":"","source":"/element","queryKey":{},"chunks":["element"]},"urlOriginal":"/session/e2fa7700-1bea-11e4-bd11-83e129ae286e/element"}}'
>   ; Screenshot: available via screen

Does anyone have idea what is wrong with this?

## --------------------------------------

Edit:
thx guys for answers
I finally find a solution for my problem. 
xpath was good (but in fact fragile)

I use firefox driver and i saw problem - ad.

I would have to skip them by that and I decided to use another page without this ad:
http://www.eskago.pl/radio

and finnaly, thx alecxe - I use this:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[@class="radio-tab-button"]/span/strong').click()
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//p[@class="onAirStreamId_999"]/strong')
print element.text
```

and work perfectly.

Comment: `Unable to find element with xpath \'/html/body/div[3]/div[1]/section[2]/div/div/div[2]/ul/li[2]/a[2]\'`

Comment: Do you know what that message means?

Comment: You need to learn how to write proper XPath. Try this: http://www.zvon.org/xxl/XPathTutorial/General/examples.html

Comment: @Siking, you might be right, but it's hard to follow that kind of advice without more specificity. What is it about the XPath expression that you think is important to improve?

Comment: @LarsH It is painfully obvious the OP does not even know what an XPath is, let alone how to construct one; the OP has not done the most basic research. I am sorry, but I am not good enough to be able to teach someone even the basics of XPath in 600 characters or less, other than to point them at a tutorial which I myself started with several years ago.

Comment: @SiKing: see alecxe's answer for an example of criticism that is specific enough to be helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The xpath you provided is a very fragile one, now wonder you get a `NoSuchElementException` exception.

Instead, rely on the `a` tag's class name, there is a current playing song inside:

```
<a class="playlist_small" href="http://www.eskago.pl/radio/eska-warszawa?noreload=yes">
    <img style="width:41px;" src="http://t-eska.cdn.smcloud.net/common/l/Q/s/lQ2009158Xvbl.jpg/ru-0-ra-45,45-n-lQ2009158Xvbl_jessie_j_bang_bang.jpg" alt="">
    <strong>Jessie J, Ariana Grande, Nicki Minaj</strong>
    <span>Bang Bang</span>
</a>
```

Here's the sample code:

```
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[@class="playlist_small"]/strong')
print element.text
```

---

Well, another way to retrieve the current playing song - is to mimic the JSONP response the website is making for the playlist:

```
>>> import requests
>>> import json
>>> import re
>>> response = requests.get('http://static.eska.pl/m/playlist/channel-999.jsonp')
>>> json_data = re.match('jsonp\((.*?)\);', response.content).group(1)
>>> songs = json.loads(json_data)
>>> current_song = songs[0]
>>> [artist['name'] for artist in current_song['artists']]
[u'David Guetta', u'Showtek', u'Vassy']
>>> current_song['name']
u'Bad'
```

Comment: @OP: or with CSS.. `a.playlist_small > strong`

Comment: I think your second code sample is not valid. what is `re` and `json` ?

Comment: Thanks, I finnaly find a solution with xpath, but your second code with jsonp is more intresting and i think is a fastest way. I dont now what that jsonp stuff is, but I'm curious from where you got this link with jsonp ?

Comment: @malloc I've just used browser developer tools and inspected all requests going out.

Answer (score 1):

As alecxe mentioned, that xpath is going to break if there are any changes in the structure of the page.

A much simpler xpath expression that will work is this:  `//li[2]/a[2]`