# Finding xpaths on pages running script

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

Im trying to scrape a webpage using selenium. The xpaths suggested by inspecting the page and right clicking are of an unstable kind (/html/body/table[2]/tbody/tr[1]/td/form/table/tbody/tr[2]) . So I tried the following solution instead:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome("path")
driver.get("https://www.bundesfinanzhof.de/entscheidungen/entscheidungen-online")
time.sleep(1)
links=driver.find_element_by_xpath('//tr[@class="SuchForm"]')
```

or even

```
links=driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@class="SuchForm"]')
```

don't return any results. However earlier on in the page I can obtain:

```
links=driver.find_element_by_xpath('//iframe')
links.get_attribute('src')
```

It seems that after:

```
<script language="JavaScript" src="/rechtsprechung/jscript/list.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

I can no longer get to any of the elements. 
[How do I determine the correct XPath?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31325232/how-do-i-determine-the-correct-xpath)
suggests that parts within a script are impossible to parse. However, the path I am after seems to me not to be within a  path. Am I misinterpretting how scripts work on a page ?

For instance, later on there is a path:

```
/html/body/table[2]/tbody/tr[1]/td/script
```

I would expect this to create such a problem. I am by no means a programmer, so my understanding of this subject is limited. Can someone explain what the problem is and if possible a solution ?

Attempted using solutions from:

[Find element text using xpath in selenium-python NOt Working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41850994/find-element-text-using-xpath-in-selenium-python-not-working)

[xpath does not work with this site, pls verify](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25122873/xpath-does-not-work-with-this-site-pls-verify)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `table` is located inside an `iframe`, so you need to switch to that `iframe` before handling required `tr`:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait as wait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver.get("https://www.bundesfinanzhof.de/entscheidungen/entscheidungen-online")
wait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH,"//iframe[@src='https://juris.bundesfinanzhof.de/cgi-bin/rechtsprechung/list.py?Gericht=bfh&Art=en']")))
link = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//tr[@class="SuchForm"]')
```

Use `driver.switch_to.default_content()` to switch back from `iframe`