# click() method not working inside a frame in selenium python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium

i have written parameters in webpage & applying them by selecting apply button. 
1. apply button is getting clicked for web elements outside frame using below command 
browser1.find_element_by_name("action").click()

2. apply button not getting clicked when saving the paramters inside a frame of web page using same command
   browser1.find_element_by_name("action").click()

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Finding xpaths on pages running script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43778486/finding-xpaths-on-pages-running-script)

Answer (score 4):

you need to switch to iframe

fist you need to find the iframe then switch to it then click

```
driver.switch_to_frame(driver.find_element_by_tag_name("iframe"))
```

or you could use xpath to locate the element

`driver.find_element_by_xpath("//iframe[]")`

Comment: you have no idea how happy I am, you solved my problem! thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

I do not know the Python syntax, but in Selenium you have to switch to the frame much like you would switch to a new tab or window before performing your click.

The syntax in Java would be: `driver.switchTo().frame();`

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by the others:

```
 WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH,"//iframe[]"))) #elements are in a iframe, have to select it first
```

If there is a chance that it doesn't show up immediately you might want to build in this wait function.
Tells python to wait for max 10 secs, until frame is available and switches to it right away. I use Xpath to track down the iframe

Dont know how new you are, so provided the imports below:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Credit for this solution goes to @Andersson
[Finding xpaths on pages running script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43778486/finding-xpaths-on-pages-running-script)
Upvote him there.

Couldn't find the duplicate report button. Title of this post makes it easier to find then the above mentioned question. (full disclosure, the link links to one of my own questions)